# registering serivices in startup class in asp.net core with generic interface dynamically

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

```
 public interface IBLLRepo<T> 
    {
      
        T Create(T app);
   long Find(long id);
        T Update(T app);
    }

 public class  CustomTDRUser : IBLLRepo<CustomTDRUser>
    {
      
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public long? ApplicationId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public long? DeptId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public long? DesgnId { get; set; }
      public long Find(long id)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
 

        public CustomTDRUser Create(CustomTDRUser app)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public CustomTDRUser Update(CustomTDRUser app)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
 
    services.AddTransient(typeof(IBLLRepo<CustomTDRUser>), typeof(CustomTDRUser));
```

> i dont want to add each class in startup like this i want register these class dynamically which inherits genric interface

i tried many solution its throwing error
*: 'Open generic service type 'TestingCore.Repositories.IBLLRepo`1[T]' requires registering an open generic implementation type. (Parameter 'descriptors)*

if i use this code given below link[githubgenericinterfacelink](https://gist.github.com/GetoXs/5caf0d8cfe6faa8a855c3ccef7c5a541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) for this. It’s a package that allows you to register services with the DI container based on conventions that you can define yourself.

In your case, you have a single interface `IBLLRepo<T>` and want to register the implementation for any `T`.

```cs
services.Scan(scan => scan
    // look in the assembly which contains the Startup class
    .FromAssemblyOf<Startup>()

    // Find all classes that are an IBLLRepo
    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(typeof(IBLLRepo<>)))
        // register them as the interface they implement
        .AsImplementedInterface()
        // with a transient lifetime
        .WithTransientLifetime()
);
```

So if you had the following classes:

```cs
public class CustomTDRUser : IBLLRepo<CustomTDRUser> { … }
public class CustomTDRCustomer : IBLLRepo<CustomTDRCustomer> { … }
public class CustomTDRProduct : IBLLRepo<CustomTDRProduct> { … }
```

then this would result in the following registrations:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IBLLRepo<CustomTDRUser>, CustomTDRUser>();
services.AddTransient<IBLLRepo<CustomTDRCustomer>, CustomTDRCustomer>();
services.AddTransient<IBLLRepo<CustomTDRProduct>, CustomTDRProduct>();
```